# Boto3: Is there a way to batch get items using hash range keys from dynamodb?

Tags: python, boto, boto3

I see from their documentation you can batch_get_item for single items

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_get_item

but I'm not quite sure how to get items from tables with hash range keys. Particularly batch getting items with just the hash value, is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

you can follow this code:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
r = dynamodb.batch_get_item(RequestItems={
            'TABLE_NAME': {
                'Keys': [
                    {
                        'myPrimaryKey': "123",
                        'mySortKey': "65894"
                    },
                    {
                        'myPrimaryKey': "123",
                        'mySortKey': "65004"
                    },
                    {
                        'myPrimaryKey': "123",
                        'mySortKey': "69654"
                    }
                ],
            },
})

print(r["Responses"]["TABLE_NAME"])
print(r["UnprocessedKeys"])
```